# ¿Como guardar entidades dependientes de otras con JPA (Java Persistence API)?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Actualmente estoy desarrollando una api-rest con spring-boot, cuyos servicios serán llamados desde una aplicación en angular, se está usando el SQL server como manejador de base de datos. Tengo las siguientes tablas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy capturando los datos de un asegurado, a través de un formulario en angular

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La relación que tengo entre estas dos entidades es uno a uno, un Asegurado es una persona, asi tengo definida sus clases:

**ASEGURADO**

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import java.sql.Time;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Assureds")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class Assured extends ParentEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5015666908034563954L;

    public Assured() {
        super();
    }

    @Column(name = "Assuredtype_Id", nullable = true) 
        private Integer assuredtypeId;    

    @Column(name = "Person_Id", nullable = false) 
    private int personId;

    @Column(name = "Applicantnumber", nullable = true) 
    private Integer applicantNumber;

    @Column(name = "Deceaseddate", nullable = true)
    private Date deceasedDate;

    @Column(name = "Deceasedlocality", nullable = true)
    private String deceasedLocality;

    @Column(name = "Since", nullable = true) 
    private Time since;

    @Column(name = "Until", nullable = true) 
    private Time until;

    /*Un asegurado es una persona */
    @OneToOne(cascade= {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="Person_Id", referencedColumnName="id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public Person person;



    public Integer getAssuredtypeId() {
        return assuredtypeId;
    }

    public void setAssuredtypeId(Integer assuredtypeId) {
        this.assuredtypeId = assuredtypeId;
    }

    public int getPersonId() {
        return personId;
    }

    public void setPersonId(int personId) {
        this.personId = personId;
    }

    public Integer getApplicantNumber() {
        return applicantNumber;
    }

    public void setApplicantNumber(Integer applicantNumber) {
        this.applicantNumber = applicantNumber;
    }

    public Time getSince() {
        return since;
    }

    public void setSince(Time since) {
        this.since = since;
    }

    public Time getUntil() {
        return until;
    }

    public void setUntil(Time until) {
        this.until = until;
    }

    public AssuredType getAssuredtype() {
        return assuredtype;
    }

    public void setAssuredtype(AssuredType assuredtype) {
        this.assuredtype = assuredtype;
    }

    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }

    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }

    public Date getDeceasedDate() {
        return deceasedDate;
    }

    public void setDeceasedDate(Date deceasedDate) {
        this.deceasedDate = deceasedDate;
    }

    public String getDeceasedLocality() {
        return deceasedLocality;
    }

    public void setDeceasedLocality(String deceasedLocality) {
        this.deceasedLocality = deceasedLocality;
    }

}
```

**PERSONA**

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Persons")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)

public class Person extends ParentEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5015666908034563954L;

    public Person() {
        super();
    }


    @Column(name = "Name", nullable = false) 
    private String name;    

    @Column(name = "Lastname", nullable = false) 
    private String lastName;    

    @Column(name = "Picture_Id", nullable = true) 
    private Integer pictureId;

    @Column(name = "Dni", nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String dni;  

    @Column(name = "Email", nullable = false, length = 255) 
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "Nationality", nullable = true, length = 255) 
    private String nationality;

    @Column(name = "Birthdate", nullable = true, length = 255) 
    private Date birthDate;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="person")
    private Set<Assured> assured;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Integer getPictureId() {
        return pictureId;
    }

    public void setPictureId(Integer pictureId) {
        this.pictureId = pictureId;
    }

    public FileUpload getFileUpload() {
        return fileUpload;
    }

    public void setFileUpload(FileUpload fileUpload) {
        this.fileUpload = fileUpload;
    }

    public String getDni() {
        return dni;
    }

    public void setDni(String dni) {
        this.dni = dni;
    }

    public Gender getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(Gender gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public List<Phone> getPhones() {
        return Phones;
    }

    public void setPhones(List<Phone> phones) {
        Phones = phones;
    }

    public List<Address> getAddresses() {
        return this.Addresses;
    }

    public void setAddresses(List<Address> addresses) {
        this.Addresses = addresses;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        Addresses.add(address);
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getNationality() {
        return nationality;
    }

    public void setNationality(String nationality) {
        this.nationality = nationality;
    }

    public Date getBirthDate() {
        return birthDate;
    }

    public void setBirthDate(Date birthDate) {
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }


}
```

**PARENTENTITY**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Access;
import javax.persistence.AccessType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;

@MappedSuperclass
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class ParentEntity implements Serializable{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2890482081142183458L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id", unique = true, nullable = false)

    private Integer id;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

Y este es mi controlador donde defino las url

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

@RestController
public class AssuredController {
    @Autowired
    protected AssuredService assuredService;
    protected ObjectMapper mapper;

     @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/assured/saveOrUpdate",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public RestResponse saveOrUpdate(@RequestBody String assuredJSON) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        this.mapper= new ObjectMapper();
        Assured assured= this.mapper.readValue(assuredJSON,Assured.class);
        this.assuredService.save(assured);
        return new RestResponse(HttpStatus.OK.value(), "Operacion Exitosa");
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/assured/getAll", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Assured> getAll() {
        return this.assuredService.findAll();
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/assured/delete", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void deleteUser(@RequestBody String assuredJson) throws Exception {
        this.mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        Assured assured = this.mapper.readValue(assuredJson, Assured.class);

        if (assured.getId()==0) {
            throw new Exception("El id esta nulo");
        }
        this.assuredService.delete(assured.getId());
    }
}
```

**REPOSITORIO**

```
package dao;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import com.sotec.BestLegalAssistance.model.Assured;

public interface AssuredRepository extends JpaRepository<Assured, Integer>{
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Assured save(Assured assured);
    void delete(int id);
}
```

**La api me guarda, elimina y edita perfectamente cuando le mando las entidades por separado, es decir capturo los datos de la persona, la guardo, creo un metodo para traerme la persona guardada, le saco su id y procedo a guardar el asegurado con el id de la persona que me traje.
LLevo 1 mes estudiando spring como tal, soy novato.

Lo que quiero hacer es mandarle desde la front-end los datos de asegurado con su objeto persona, y me cree las dos entidades en una sola petición, sabiendo que un asegurado tiene una clave foránea del Id de persona. Cuando intento insertar el asegurado me sale error en la consola de java diciendo que el Id_persona no puede ser null, por lo que veo, no me crea la persona y cuando intenta guardar el asegurado no encuentra el Id_Persona.

No se si se pueda hacer lo que pido, me he documentado con respecto al tema pero no consigo un ejemplo que ayude a implementarlo
**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu objeto padre Assured debes ocupar la anotación

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

De este modo hibernate sabe que si recibe el objeto con su hijo que en este caso es Persona debe persistir ambos objetos.

Un ejemplo que aunque está en inglés es útil está en este [link](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-relationship-example-annotation/)

Comment: Gracias, me funcionó, con ese pequeño cambio, pude guardar un asegurado con la persona, sin la necesidad de guardarlos por separados, todavía tengo poco conocimiento sobre el funcionamientos de algunas cosas